# Trouble with computer staying awake

Tags: windows

Got this as the reason why my computer wont sleep:

DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (RasMan)
Active RAS connection

AWAYMODE:
None.

Trying to figure out what it is and what it means, and if I can remove/fix it to allow my computer to sleep.

Comment: The first thing I would try is reinstalling windows

Comment: You didn't specify which version of Windows you're using. Also, has this problem manifested itself recently, for instance after you've installed some new software or hardware? In that case, you could try uninstalling the software/hardware to isolate the problem. Or you could roll back your system to a previous Restore Point and see if that helps.

Comment: @BaliC That is the **first** thing you would try? I would recommend trying other solutions before you hit the big reset button ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I know it seems a bit drastic :) but I've seen too many problems like this where the diagnostics take much longer than just going for a reinstall, just MHO though.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/internet-connection-not-allow-the-computer-suspend/feae1968-ccf6-47d7-b4d2-813eebd457b8):

```
powercfg -requestsoverride Service RasMan SYSTEM
```

Might resolve the issue.

Maybe you have an open dialup connection that causes this.